# Get value from <script> tag to t t-esc tag in Odoo 12

Tags: javascript, templates, geolocation, odoo, odoo-12

I was trying to get current coordinates of a location in Odoo. I got longitude and latitude in alert from a code below:

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

                            <p id="demo"></p>

                            <script>
                                var x = document.getElementById("demo");

                                function getLocation() {
                                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                                } else {
                                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                                }
                                }
                                function showPosition(position) {
                                x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                                "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
                                }
                            </script>
```

But how can we get these coordinates in my Odoo fields gps_coordinates_latitude and gps_coordinates_longitude respectively? Here is my template file in Odoo:

```
<template id="create_case" name="Create Case">
    <t t-call="website.layout">
        <div class="container">
            <script>
                var x = document.getElementById("demo");

                function getLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                }
                }

                function showPosition(position) {
                var lati = position.coords.latitude; <t t-esc="gps_coordinates_latitude"/>
                alert(position.coords.longitude);
                x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
                alert(position.coords.latitude);
                }
            </script>

            <h1 class="text-center mt16 mb16">Create Case</h1>
            <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
            <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <form action="/mycase/process" method="POST" class="form-horizontal mt32" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error and 'case_title' in error and 'has-error' or ''}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="case_title">Case Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="case_title" required="True"
                           t-attf-value="#{case_title or ''}"/>
                </div>
                <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error and 'case_description' in error and 'has-error' or ''}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="case_description">Case Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="case_description" required="True"
                           t-attf-value="#{case_description or ''}"/>
                </div>
                <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error and 'case_type' in error and 'has-error' or ''}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="case_type">Case Type</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="case_type" name="case_type" required="True">
                        <t t-foreach="case_type" t-as="case_type">
                            <option t-attf-value="#{case_type.id}">
                                <t t-esc="case_type.name"/>
                            </option>
                        </t>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error and 'project' in error and 'has-error' or ''}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="project_name">Projects</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="project_name" required="True">
                        <t t-foreach="projects" t-as="project">
                            <option t-attf-value="#{project.id}">
                                <t t-esc="project.name"/>
                            </option>
                        </t>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label class="control-label" for="gps_coordinates_latitude">Latitude</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gps_coordinates_latitude"
                           t-attf-value="#{gps_coordinates_latitude or ''}"/>
                </div>

                <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error and 'case_description' in error and 'has-error' or ''}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="gps_coordinates_longitude">Longitude</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gps_coordinates_longitude" required="True"
                           t-attf-value="#{gps_coordinates_longitude or ''}"/>
                </div>

                <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error and 'ratings' in error and 'has-error' or ''}">
                    <label class="col-form-label" for="ratings">Ratings</label>
                    <select class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="ratings" required="false"
                            widget="priority">
                        <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="good">Good</option>
                        <option value="very_good">Very Good</option>
                        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error and 'attachment' in error and 'has-error' or ''}">
                    <label class="col-form-label" for="attachment">Attachments</label>
                    <input id='attachment' type="file" class="form-control o_website_form_input"
                           name="attachment" multiple="true" data-show-preview="true"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit Case</button>
                </div>
                <div class="oe_chatter">
                    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to use the t t-esc as soon as you are getting the value directly on the js.

you should modify your js and assign the value to your input fields `gps_coordinates_latitude` and `gps_coordinates_longitude`, something like

```
document.getElementsByName("gps_coordinates_latitude")[0].value = position.coords.latitude;
document.getElementsByName("gps_coordinates_longitude")[0].value = position.coords.longitude;
```

hope this solves your problem.

Comment: hello @atul, thanks alot for your prompt response. I have tried your solution but it is not working for me.

Comment: Or anything else we need to add?

Comment: @GautamBothra, put your <script> tag below the </form>. it should work.

Comment: @GautamBothra, check this working fiddle> https://jsfiddle.net/atularvind/67m0p2su/1/

Comment: ok thanks... now it's working. I have to use "getElementById" instead of getElementsByName as i have multiple names in my script. So i think thats why it's not working.

Comment: can you do one more help? I want to use these coordinates in map like google map shows location pinned according to these coordinates. May i get a hint or some useful links related to that please?